# Counting by group, with respect to a specific column, keeping into account the amount of NA's

Tags: r, sum, data.table, conditional-statements, grouping

I would like my "count by group" to take into account NA values from a specified c

```
library(data.table)
sample <- fread("
1,0,2,2,cat X
3,4,3,NA,cat Y
1,0,2,2,cat X
3,4,3,0,cat Y
")
names(sample) <- c("A","B","C", "D", "cat")

sample <- sample[,observations:= .N, by=cat]

   A B C  D   cat observations
1: 1 0 2  2 cat X           2
2: 3 4 3 NA cat Y           2
3: 1 0 2  2 cat X           2
4: 3 4 3  0 cat Y           2
```

I would like be able to specify that I want to count the available observations with respect to column `D`. Because there is an `NA` for `cat Y`, with respect to `D` it has only one observation.

Desired output:

```
   A B C  D   cat observations
1: 1 0 2  2 cat X           2
2: 3 4 3 NA cat Y           1
3: 1 0 2  2 cat X           2
4: 3 4 3  0 cat Y           1
```

Is there a way to specify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.N` behaves irrespective of a column (like `dplyr::n`), so you can `sum` the non-`NA` values of column `D`:

```r
sample[, observations := sum(!is.na(D)), by = cat][]

   A B C  D   cat observations
1: 1 0 2  2 cat X            2
2: 3 4 3 NA cat Y            1
3: 1 0 2  2 cat X            2
4: 3 4 3  0 cat Y            1
```